# Declaration of class must be compatible with interface error in telegram bot package

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using [irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk) to make a telegram bot.

but when I installed the `dev-develop` first I got this error :

```
    Cannot use Telegram\Bot\Objects\Message as Message because the name is already in use {"exception":"[object]  
 (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 64): Cannot use Telegram\\Bot\\Objects\\Message as Message because the name is already in use at D:\\wamp\\www\\botshop\\vendor\\irazasyed\\telegram-bot-sdk\\src\\Methods\\Payments.php:5)
```

But after that when I commented `use Telegram\Bot\Objects\Message;` in line 5 of [Payments.php](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/blob/develop/src/Methods/Payments.php) , error not shown again.

But another problem was created that said :

```
Declaration of App\Commands\StartCommand::handle($arguments) must be compatible with Telegram\Bot\Commands\Command::handle()
```

this is a simple `StartCommand` that is also used by itself package in all example of creating new command :

```
class StartCommand extends Command
{
    protected $name = "start";

    protected $description = "Start Command to get you started";

    public function handle($arguments)
    {
        $this->replyWithMessage(['text' => 'Hello! Welcome to our bot, Here are our available commands:']);

    }
}
```

I'm using php7.0.10 and laravel 5.5.

Answer (score 2):

The `handle` function doesn't take any argument by default on the `Telegram\Bot\Commands\Command` class.

Since you don't use the `$arguments` variable, you can delete it from the `handle` function parameters and your code should work again.

Comment: in the version 3 that I used before it gets an `$arguments` that I used it in many cases. in this case I must to remove those but how can I send my custom parameters?

Comment: Note that I never used this library, but as from what I have looked up on the project, it looks like this branch is sort of unstable & fastmoving which may not be a great idea for production. Their documentation seems outdated as of the latest Telegram lib they are using.